Access violation reading location 0x31322d50
I'm having an allocation problem in a C application
When debugging, I see that the problem occurs in this line:
long **matr=(long **)calloc(my_size, sizeof(long *));

Usually, my_size is less than 1000, and the error doesn't occur.
But there's one case where it is around 2000, and the error occurs.
The output window shows this:
First-chance exception at 0x77cb79ce in myprogram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x31322d50.
What should I do to avoid this problem?
It's a very old program. I'd like to avoid changing this line, that is called in a lot of parts.
But I hope there is something that I could do before this
When I open then Memory window, on Debug options on VS, this address shows "??"
Seems that this is an invalid memory address, but it doesn't seem that I'm trying to allocate a huge amount of memory. The memory usage is not achieving 50%, and the application is not using more than 300MB

first calloc prototype is
void *calloc(size_t number,size_t size);

And your code
long **matr=(long **)calloc(my_size, sizeof(long *));

And you want a dynamic array of long pointers. Your code is right.
I think that your problem with your program is your heap size. This is why you get an error with a 2000 but not with 1000. I dont know what compiler/linker you are using but for example in microcontrollers it is very small. At least this is what would happens if heap size is too small.
Check your heap size in linker and problem is probably gone. Another option is to use OS allocation functions and then you dont need to worry about heap size.
calloc function in this link you can find about heap size (_HEAP_MAXREQ) for windows, but based in your system could be different

Thank you
But it seems that it didn't work
I'm using Windows
In malloc, this is defined:
#ifdef  _WIN64
#define _HEAP_MAXREQ    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
#else
#define _HEAP_MAXREQ    0xFFFFFFE0
#endif
I included in my code:
#define _HEAP_MAXREQ    0xFFFFFFFF
which replaced the previous definition, but the same happened
I also tried to change the "heap reserve size", on project options, but nothing changed

@RenatoB Try to find the exact point, with a for, try from 1000 to 2000 to write. Finding the exact point can give us some extra information, for example, if pointer is 32 bits and it fails after 4096 bytes (what would be 1024 entries exactly) it would be interesting information.

@RenatoB if from 1000 to 2000 it doesnt fails, then it is not about that pointer, probably other portion of the code.

@RenatoB there is another option, maybe other portion of the code is overwriting your pointer area, that happens if you are not very experienced. To check this, list the pointers address in a file or something like that, it must be more or less consecutive.

@RenatoB Another thing, this is creating the memory space for pointers but not the pointers itself, I have supposed that you created them after.
